# turning an array into a variable number of arguments

Tags: c, printf

In pseudo code, I want put an arbitrary number of arguments to printf depending on the length of the argv, where the argv[1] is the format string.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf(argv[1], argv[2], ...);
}
```

Uses can call the program as `./prog "%s %s" a b`, `./prog "%s %s %s" a b c`, and so on.

Could anybody let me know how to achieve this in C?

Comment: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.bin/printf/printf.c (BSD source for the standard printf command line utility which does what you're being asked to do.) You cannot fabricate an argument list to `printf`, so you have to parse the format string yourself. The linked code is an example.

Comment: could do a bit of the old macro preprocessing

Comment: How do you intend to deal with non-string format strings?

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop for this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<argc;i++) {
      printf("%s", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. argv[1] is a format string that governs all the rest of argv[2] .... Uses can call the program as `./prog "%s %s" a b`, `./prog "%s %s %s" a b c`, and so on.

Comment: @user1424739 In that case, you'll probably need to parse the format string yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I just hacked together right now, it does does minimal parsing of the string and leaves most of it up to `printf`. It should also work with any number of arguments. Of course, since arguments are passed as `char *`s through the command line, this will only work with `%s` and its variants (and `%%`, but not sure if that counts as a format specifier).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <format string>[ <args>]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    // These pointers will constantly jump from format spec. to format spec.
    char *last_fmt = argv[1], *next_fmt, *next_next_fmt;
    char *buf = NULL; // a buffer to hold a substring of argv[1]
    unsigned i = 2;       // Used to iterate over argv[2+]
    while (1)
    {
        next_fmt = last_fmt - 2;
        do
        {
            if ((next_fmt = strchr(next_fmt + 2, '%')) == NULL)
            {
                /* Your compiler may warn about this line specifically (it did for me),
                   but rest assured that there are indeed no format specifiers
                   here really, printf is just needed for printing "%%"s as "%"s */
                printf(last_fmt);
                return 0;
            }
        } while (next_fmt[1] == '%');
        next_next_fmt = next_fmt - 1;
        do
        {
            if ((next_next_fmt = strchr(next_next_fmt + 2, '%')) == NULL)
            {
                printf(last_fmt == argv[1] ? last_fmt : next_fmt,
                       argv[i]);
                return 0;
            }
        } while (next_next_fmt[1] == '%');
        buf = malloc(next_next_fmt - last_fmt + 1);
        memcpy(buf, last_fmt, next_next_fmt - last_fmt);
        buf[next_next_fmt - last_fmt] = '\0';
        printf(buf, argv[i]);
        free(buf);
        ++i;
        last_fmt = next_next_fmt;
    }
}
```

An example of running:

```
./a.out "Hello %.2s World! %s" "foo" "bar"
Hello fo World! bar

./a.out "Hello %10s World!" "foo" "bar"
Hello        foo World!

./a.out "Hello %5.2s World!" "random"
Hello    ra World!

./a.out
Usage: ./a.out <format string>[ <args>]

./a.out "Hello %%s World %s" "a"
Hello %s World a

./a.out "%s %s %s" "a" "b" "c"
a b c
```

You could build upon this yourself, but if you want to handle other format specifiers, you'll have to do actual parsing of the string. At that point, you would basically be creating another `printf`.

You also might be a bit worried about the use of a not-string-literal passed to `printf`, but this is safe. There is guaranteed to be exactly 1 format specifier in each place I use `printf` (except in the first `do` loop, but there it is guaranteed to not have any arguments).

Comment: it will explode for `./a.out "Hello %%s World %s" "a"`

Comment: @tstanisl hmm, you're right. That seems a bit tough to fix based on the way my program currently works, but I'll at least try working out the `%%` issue :/

Comment: @tstanisl with the help of an inner `do ... while` loop, the `%%` issue has been fixed (I think). Thanks.

Comment: Still fails for `/a.out "%s%%" "a"` producing `as%` rather than `a%`

Comment: @tstanisl just had to replicate the loop for `next_next_fmt` too, works now.

Comment: This general approach is probably the best available option for solving the problem as presented by the OP.  The details are tricky to get completely right however.  This particular implementation has a buffer-overflow vulnerability, for instance, plus a bit of UB involving variable `next_fmt`.  There may be other issues.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I assume you mean that the substring going into `buf` may exceed its bounds in the buffer overflow part, but where is there UB from `next_fmt`? It *can* go out of the string's bounds in `next_fmt = last_fmt - 2`, but since I access it afterwards with `next_fmt + 2` in the `strchr`, I think this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1, yes, the buffer overflow is from copying the an argument into a fixed-size buffer.  The UB is from the first evaluation of `next_fmt = last_fmt - 2`.  You cannot use pointer arithmetic to derive a pointer to before the start of an object from a pointer (in)to that object, even if you never dereference the result.  Where by "cannot" I mean that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @JohnBollinger fixed the buffer overflow issue by using `malloc` at least. Unfortunately, based on the way this currently works, removing the UB from the `next_fmt` might be slightly more problematic. I can't personally think of a scenario where the UB here could actually cause unpredictable behavior, but eh, it's probably undefined for a reason. I could maybe put a check somewhere in the loop before assigning `next_fmt`, but that would be yet another condition check.

Answer (score 0):

> how to achieve this in C?

C language does *not* have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). You can't "dynamically create function calls" or inspect and then change your own source code. You have to know *at compilation time* how many arguments you are passing to a function. While it is simple to do `printf("%s %s", "a", "b)` **inside** C language, if you pass the same data to a program that *was* written in C language you have parse the data and write the logic yourself.

Such parser would take the string `"%s %s"` find the `%s` sequences and replace them for  the string `"a"` and `"b"` and also print the space in between, etc. That parser has to be written *in C* and is basically a duplication of what [`printf` **program**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (not `printf()` C function) does. You may want to read some implementations of `printf` program: ex. [coreutils printf.c](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/printf.c#L446) or [freebsd printf.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.bin/printf/printf.c#L402).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great idea to begin with, it will be super-vulnerable to all manner of exploits, typos and bugs. But if you insist, you could do a ***dirty*** hack as follows:

Assuming the format string in argv[1] is `%s %s %s`, then each we can divide this string length by 3 to get the number of strings. Save for the final one, which isn't followed by a trailing space. So `strlen(argv[1]) + 1` then divide by 3:

```
#define STR_N ((strlen(argv[1])+1)/3)
```

Next up we can take advantage of printf ignoring trailing arguments not corresponding to the format string. So we could do `printf(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);` just fine without actually passing that many arguments, long as the format string contains the correct amount of conversion specifiers. For example:

```
#define ARGV_LIST \
argv[2],\
argv[3],\
argv[4],\
argv[5],\
argv[6],\
argv[7],\
argv[8],\
argv[9]\

printf(argv[1], ARGV_LIST);
```

Then cook up something to convert the indices and make sure that array out of bounds never occurs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_N ((strlen(argv[1])+1)/3)
#define INDEX(n) (STR_N>n? (n+2) : 0)

#define ARGV_LIST \
argv[INDEX(0)],\
argv[INDEX(1)],\
argv[INDEX(2)],\
argv[INDEX(3)],\
argv[INDEX(4)],\
argv[INDEX(5)],\
argv[INDEX(6)],\
argv[INDEX(7)],\
argv[INDEX(8)],\
argv[INDEX(9)]\

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  printf(argv[1], ARGV_LIST);
  return 0;   
}
```

Tested in Windows with `prog.exe "%s %s %s %s %s" hello this is a test` gives output:

```
hello this is a test
```